# Using the Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api create() method to create a new shipment

Tags: magento-1.9, error, programmatically, shipment, create

I am making a connector for Magento, where orders from Magento are pushed into our system, then get shipments created that need to be pulled back into Magento and converted to the right format. In Magento 2, this is accomplished with **`shipRepo->create()`**

I believe, but I'm struggling to find the correct Magento 1 solution. I have the order's increment ID from the original order, so I'm trying to use that. Right now here is what I'm trying:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
if($order->canShip()) {
        $itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
        $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
        $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
        $shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId, $itemQty,null,true,false);
}
```

However, when I try this out, I get a `data_invalid` error. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm basing my code off of [this inchoo post](https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-make-order-shipment-from-code/) and [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055923/magento-how-do-i-programmatically-ship-orders) but I'm pretty sure it's still failing on the `create` method.

I'm curious why we set `$shipment` twice. Does that first assignment actually accomplish anything?

Comment: More Details needed. Where exactly are your files located and what have you changed?

Comment: I'm making my own module and this is a function within a cron job. The file is under `{baseDir}/app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model` is that what you're asking? I don't know what you mean by what have I changed...

Comment: Please try with "$shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId, $itemQty,null,false,false);" instead of "$shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId, $itemQty,null,true,false);" in your code. Also refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58606/customer-shipment-confirmation-email-not-being-sent

Comment: So that still didn't work, I guess the problem is with `$itemQty` because when I replaced it with `array()` then the shipment created, but I have no control over the data in it. Like what if it was a partial shipment and I didn't actually ship all of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a lot of trial and error I think I figured it out.

First of all, I've seen this method all over the place, but it is a mess. I would like to say I managed to cleaned it up into something that is actually usable.

This line: `$itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();` sets $itemQty to a number, a count, but the `create()` method requires an array! That was ultimately the reason I was getting a `data_invalid` error, and when I changed

`$shipment->create($orderId, $itemQty,null,true,false);`

to

`$shipment->create($orderId, array(),null,true,false);`

it *kind of* fixed things, in that I no longer got an error. But I don't want to just blindly accept all quantities on the shipment. I want to accept only what is actually on the shipment (duh) so I had to figure out the right way to do it.

First thing to do was make a `$itemQtys` array of the format

```
array(
  'order_item_id'=>$qty,
  'order_item_id'=>$qty,
  'order_item_id'=>$qty
)
```

Then just create the API and shipment. But their way of making the API is very... not Magento-y. So I changed it from

`$shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();`

to

`$newShip = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api');`

For me, it looked something like this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
if($order->canShip()) {
    $itemQtys = array();

    //cycle through the items on the shipment and add them to the array
    //note: you must previously define $shipItems from your shipment
    foreach($shipItems as $newItem) {
        $itemQtys[$newItem->getOrderItemId()] = $newItem->getQty();
    }

    //create the shipment
    $shipApi= Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api');
    $shipId = $shipApi->create($orderId, $itemQtys);

    //get the actual shipment if you want to further manipulate it
    $magShip = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipId);
}
```

I also experimented with using `prepareShipment` in the form of

```
$magShip = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQtys);
```

However, this did not succeed in actually creating the shipment, nor was it necessary in my solution, so I'm still not totally sure what it's supposed to be used for.

## Conclusion:

From the original post, only the last two lines did anything. To create a shipment programmatically, create a `$itemQtys` array and then call the `create` function.

Source code was also useful from [here](http://freegento.com/doc/d9/d1a/class_mage___sales___model___order___shipment___api.html#4e3d56de1fb4db90a1018c576b547c25).